# Javascript map function with destructuring, how to get ojbect value with destructured property?

Tags: javascript

```
Input: equations = [["a","b"],["b","c"]], 
values = [2.0,3.0], queries = [["a","c"],["b","a"],["a","e"],["a","a"],["x","x"]]
Output: [6.00000,0.50000,-1.00000,1.00000,-1.00000]



var calcEquation = function(equations, values, queries) {
    let graph = new Map();
    let result = Array.from({length: queries.length}).fill(0)

console.log(result)

equations.map(([x,y], i) => {
    if(!graph.get(x)) graph.set(x, {});
    if(!graph.get(y)) graph.set(y, {});
    graph.get(x)[y] = values[i];
    graph.get(y)[x] = 1/values[i];
})

console.log(graph)

queries.map(([x,y], i) => {
    console.log(x,y)                    --> why it works and underline code not working?
    console.log(graph[x], graph[y])     ---> problem here
    if(!graph[x] || !graph[y]) result[i] = -1;
    
})

console.log(result)
};
```

I was on solving algorithm on https://leetcode.com/problems/evaluate-division/.

The problem is that I can't get graph property with destructured values.
If i console.log(x,y) it works well, but console.log(graph[x], graph[y]) is returning the value of real string 'x'.

How can I get the proper value of object??

Comment: `equations.map(([x,y], i) => {` <-- You're misusing `Array.prototype.map`. As you're mutating entries you should use `for(of)` instead.

Comment: The answer is right in your code, just above the line in question. You use `graph.get`.

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus
Oh, what the... Why couldn't I find this myself? Tahnk so much.

Answer (score 0):

The `graph` variable is a [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) and you should use `get` method to return a specified element.

```js
console.log(graph.get(x), graph.get(y))
```